# Automate local application (similar to a browser) using Selenium

Tags: selenium-webdriver, robotframework, autoit

I have a (complete IE) browser-based application, let's call it "app".
I want to open this "app" and operate it with the Selenium Robot Framework to make it acting as a real browser.

For now, I can use the AutoIt Library to open the "app" from the local Windows.

How to use Selenium to do the automation?

(It wouldn't detect the browser existing if I use Selenium directly and I can't just use the IE driver to define this, what I need is only this "app".)

Comment: You should probably give more info about this app.  (language, run-time, how the browser is embedded...)

Comment: I once tested a similar application that was running a web interface locally. The application had a local open port that served web pages. We opened this local port with Selenium to test it and manipulated it there.